# Taylor Polynomial of $\arctan$ of given Degree and Error

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Replace the following function by its taylor polynomial of the given
>   grade, and approximate the error in the given interval:
>
> $$f(x) = \arctan(x) \textrm{ by } T_3(f,x,0) \textrm{ in } |x| \le\frac{1}{10}$$

**My solution and thoughts**

We only need the first three derivatives and the fourth one for the error

$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2} \\
f''(x) = \frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2} \\
f'''(x) = \frac{6x^2-2}{(x^2+1)^3} \\
f^{(iv)}(x) = \frac{24x(x^2-1)}{(x^2+1)^4}
$$

And by definition we know that

$$
T_3(f,x,0) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^3 \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k
$$

we get

$$
T_3(f,x,0) = x - \frac{x^3}{3}
$$

We know that

$$R_3(x) = \frac{f^{(iv)}(c)}{4!}x^4, |x| \le \frac{1}{10}$$

by plugging in the maximal value of $x = c = \frac{1}{10}$ we get for any $c$:

$$
\left|f^{(iv)}(c)\right| = \left|\frac{24c(c^2-1)}{(c^2+1)^4}\right| \le \\
\le \frac{24\cdot 99 \cdot 100^4}{1000\cdot 101^4}
$$

$$
\Rightarrow \left|R_3(x)\right| \le \frac{24\cdot 99 \cdot 100^4}{1000\cdot 101^4 \cdot 4!}\cdot\left|x^4\right| \Leftrightarrow \\
\Leftrightarrow \left|R_3(x)\right| \le \frac{10}{101^4}
$$

Is this solution correct? How can I make it more formally right? (I know I lack some mathematical formalism).

Comment: What do you think, should I approximate the fourth differential by $\frac{24c^3}{c^8}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be considered a minor addition to the answer by Mike Spivey.

Note that the fourth derivative is $0$ at $0$. So the Taylor polynomial that we get by expanding until the third derivative is **exactly the same** as the Taylor polynomial we get by expanding until the fourth derivative!

Thus you can use the formula for the remainder that involves the fifth derivative. There is not a lot of gain for the extra work, but there is some. The fifth derivative, I think, is $\dfrac{24(5x^4-10x^2+1)}{(x^2+1)^5}$.

The analysis leads to an upper bound on the error which is about one-fifth of the error upper bound we get by using the Lagrange estimate without noting that stopping at $3$ gives the same polynomial as stopping at $4$.

**Remark:** You may have worked too hard in doing the arithmetic. Let's do exactly as you did, using the fourth derivative instead of the better fifth. 
At a certain stage, you reached
$$
\left|f^{(iv)}(c)\right| = \left|\frac{24c(c^2-1)}{(c^2+1)^4}\right|
$$
Note that $c^2+1\gt 1$ and $|c^2-1|\lt 1$. So our fourth derivative has absolute value $\lt 24\cdot \dfrac{1}{10}$. We have harly given away anything in making this simple estimate. Now divide by $24$, multiply by $\left(\dfrac{1}{10}\right)^4$. We find that the absolute value of the error is $\lt 10^{-5}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your work looks good to me, except for a mistake in the last step (probably a typo).  Other than that, it's pretty much exactly the way I would hope one of my students would solve this problem.

The mistake is that you lost the $99$ in the final step, so that at the end you should have $$
\left|R_3(x)\right| \le \frac{99 \cdot 10}{101^4}.$$

(Also, the final implication is $\Rightarrow$, not $\Leftrightarrow$.  Since you're substituting a value for $x$ here the two inequalities are not equivalent.)

---

As a side note, there's an easier way to calculate the Taylor series about $0$ for $f(x) = \arctan x$.
Since $$\frac{d}{dx} \arctan x = \frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 \pm \ldots,$$ via the geometric series formula when $|x| < 1$, 
$$\arctan x = C + x - \frac{1}{3} x^3 + \frac{1}{5}x^5 - \frac{1}{7} x^7 \pm \ldots.$$
Since $\arctan 0 = 0$, we have  $C = 0$.  This gives you $$T_3(f,x,0) = x - \frac{1}{3}x^3$$ rather painlessly.

You do still need to find the fourth derivative of $\arctan x$ to use the remainder formula for Taylor polynomials, however.

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement and the additional information, great help!

Comment: @Flavius: I added one more minor comment you might want to look at.  And you're welcome!